# EJPPG0024I: Web application with context root /.Test is deployed in the application server but not registered with portal

Tags: portlet, websphere-portal

I'm using Rational Application Developer v9.5.0.3 (x64) and WebSphere Portal v8.5 CF14 (running on WAS v8.5.5.12 x64). In previous versions of RAD and portal I had no problems deploying portlets.

Now when I deploy portlet using RAD (drag&drop) I get

> ObjectModelRe I com.ibm.wps.services.registry.ObjectModelRegistry registerWASPortletApplication EJPPG0024I: Web application with context root /.Test is deployed in the application server but not registered with portal.

Why do I receive this message and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

instead of using the drag and drop, try doing run on server and selecting portal directly